# Why Karma launch an empty browser window?

Tags: karma-runner

Should Karma launch a browser that with my front-end app loaded?

I should see a landing page of my app if Karma is correctly loaded, is this correct?

If not loading my app landing page, why Karma launch a visible browser?

This is my karma.config.js 
I am learning Karma, not sure if I did everything alright.

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = {};
/*
The entry point from the referenced Webpack configuration 
has to be removed or tests will fail in weird and inscrutable 
ways. Easy enough, just define an empty entry object.
*/

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    bathPath: './dist/',
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    /* reference the Webpack configuration in the Karma configuration */
    preprocessors: {
        // './dist/bundle.js': ['webpack'],
        './test/*.js': ['webpack']
        /* application’s entry point, karama-webpack plugin requires this */
        /* you have to tell Karma that you want the karma-webpack plugin 
           to process these files. That’s what ['webpack'] does.
        */
    },
    /* 
            The plugins section is missing from my karma.config.js file. 
            When missing, Karma will load any plugins it can find in the 
            node-modules folder. Much simpler in my opinion.
    */
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [ {pattern: 'index.html', }, './test/*.js'],
    /* The files array determines which files are included in the 
       browser and which files are watched and served by Karma 
    */
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876
  });
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.  Karma loads a page which includes all your javascript and all your specs.  It then runs any specs that might be in there.  This is not *full integration* testing.  This is javascript unit testing.

If you wanted to debug in browser, you can click the `debug` button and you'll see the page that it runs.  Hit that page and check out the console and you'll see your spec output.

You'll need something more for full integration tests like `protractor` or `capybara` or ...

Probably depends on what you're using to build your site.

Comment: I saw other people using Karma do some fancy test, such as 1) click a button to test event handler 2) test front-end routing.  How should I do that using Karma in Webpack front-end project?